# Category as field value?

Tags: categories, structure, fields

Is it possible to populate an entry field with categories? When publishing a Structure page, I'd like to be able to select what category of products to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. **[WB Category Select](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wb-category-select)** is a fieldtype that does just that.

When you create a custom field of this type you can set the category group(s) and whether or not the user is allowed to select multiple categories.

It's a very handy add-on and works great!

Comment: Thanks man. I found that extension on devotee but I'm glad you confirmed it.